# Is peppermint tea autological

Tags: vocabulary, phonetics

Basically as the question says. Is peppermint tea autological because it tastes pepperminty. I know they are different words but phonetically they are identical.

If not, is there another word which describes this phenomenon?

Comment: What does 'autological' mean? And does 'peppermint tea' fulfill those criteria? If 'Peppermint tea' is autological then isn't _every_ word or phrase autological? What phenomenon are you talking about (please be more specific)?

Comment: An autological word is one that describes itself.  My favourite example is "polysyllabic" which both describes and IS a word with multiple syllables.  It's like onomatopoeia in a way

Comment: No, an autological word *describes the word*. The **word** "short" is autological because the **word** "short" is short, similarly the word "English" is in English, so "English" is autological, and so on. So far as I'm aware, no one experiences the sensation of peppermint when using the word "peppermint", so no, "peppermint" is not autological.

Comment: I don't think there's any logic at all to peppermint tea.

Comment: @HotLicks Phonetically there is though and that was the cause for my question. I am not sure but I think some of the people commenting may not see that. I am wondering whether it is just a regional accent type thing which makes it work for me.

Comment: @DaveM Thanks for your comment, I like the word polysyllabic too, I will add that to my list of favourite quirky words!! I was having a discussion the other day about how it is such a shame that palendrome isn't a palendrome.

Comment: It isn't a palindrome, either.

Comment: Aww, I don't want troll praise. :(

Comment: @JohnClifford No one controls the trolls, they just control you. :)

Comment: If I could downvote comments, I would do it to that one because you didn't say "controlls".

Comment: @JohnClifford "It isn't a palindrome, either" also isn't a palindrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Peppermint tea* is not autological because it is *pepperminty*, any more than *Witt tea* is autological because it is funny. An autological term is a term that describes itself. A similar or identical sounding term is not the term itself. If it happens to describe the original term, you have a sort of pun, but not an autology.

Comment: Yeah I guess it is more of a Pun, It sounds like there should be a word to describe it so that's why I thought I would ask. Thanks

Comment: If anything, I'd argue that peppermint is an adjective to describe the tea.

Comment: If you were going for a pun, you could say it's called that because it tastes mint tea.

Comment: @JohnClifford: That's what the original question is about, as far as I can figure. Keithin8a was asking if "peppermint tea" being (near-)homophonous to "pepperminty" makes it autological.

Comment: @sumelic That's what I thought. I'm sure there's a term for that kind of thing other than pun when it's not meant to be a joke, per se.

Comment: @JohnClifford No, no, not a pun. What’s that thing that spells the same backwards as forwards?